# Bibliographies per chapter: Citations only show [??] in the body, but proper references appear in each bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, chapters, thesis, chapterbib

I'm writing a master's thesis and need to have my references per chapter. Using a single .bib file for my bibliography, I am including each chapter in the main .tex file using \include{chap1} etc. with each chap.tex file having \bibliography{thesis.bib} for the bibliography.

When I build the PDF, each bibliography comes out correctly and containing the proper references as they appear in each chapter, but the in-text citations only appear as [??] and I get the error: 'Citation 'Diels2006' on page 2 undefined'.

I am using chapterbib for my bibliography.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath} %need this for math modes
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float} 

\usepackage
[
        a4paper,% other options: a3paper, a5paper, etc
        left=1.5in,
        right=1in,
        top=1in,
        bottom=1in,
]
{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{braket} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{hyperref,}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[list=true,listformat=simple]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib} % this is where I use chapterbib for my bibliography

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{5.5cm}\bfseries} 
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\hspace*{5.5cm}\bfseries}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\doublespace

\hypersetup{ 
    colorlinks=true,
    citecolor = blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    }
    
\setlength\parindent{1cm}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2009}{\,}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03C3}{\\sigma}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\include{frontmatter}

\newpage
{

    \hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
    \tableofcontents
}

\newpage
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{chap1}

\include{chap2}

\include{chap3}

\include{chap4}

\include{chap5}

\newpage


\end{document}
```

Here is an example of what a chap.tex file looks like:

```
\chapter{The Experiment}

Example of body text.

Example of text needing citation \cite{Diels2006}.

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{thesis.bib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you follow the compiler chain pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex?

Comment: @Mensch Yes, I compiled using the chain pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex, pdflatex. I've also compiled bibtex on each of the individual chapter .tex files.